# PHP date function is one day behind current local date

Tags: php, date

Here it's Friday, 14th July 2017.If its so then why the following code shows wrong date?

```
$curr_date = date('Y-m-d', time()); //output='2017-07-13'
```

What am i missing here?Why does the following function shows one day behind the current date?Also i want the variable to hold date exactly in 'Y-m-d' format only.

Please help me with some code snippets.Thanks.

Comment: most likely a time zone issue. Have you set your local time zone in your PHP configuration?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php to see.

Comment: You have discovered time travel :)

Comment: lol ... nice one @WheatBeak :p

Comment: *"Here it's Friday"* and the server's location is? Or are you running this locally?

Comment: You seem to not be present, same here now

Comment: @Fred-ii- come back tomorrow ;)

Comment: @Don'tPanic Only if there's an *All-you-can-eat* buffet.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Dont't Panic & @AbraCadaver for pointing me in the right direction and the solution for me is:

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata" );
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimezone($timezone );
$curr_date = $date->format( 'Y-m-d' );
```